# Do not show checkbox value if checkbox not checked

Tags: php, if-statement, checkbox

I have the following code that is used to show some custom fields.

```
<table>
    <tbody>
<?php 
foreach ($fields as $field) {
$type = $field['s_type'];
$label = $field['s_label'];
$value = Attributes::newInstance()->getValue($item_id, $field['pk_id']);
if ($type == 'checkbox') {
    if ($value == 'checked') $value = 'Yes';
    else $value = 'No';
}
?>

        <tr>
            <td class='detail_label'><?php echo $label; ?></td>
            <td class='detail_label'><?php echo $value; ?></td>
        </tr>
<?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I need to not show the content in tr when checkbox value = 'No'

Is it possible to do that?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Not show what content ?

Comment: Content in tr. Right now it returns "Label1:Yes, Label2:No, Label3:No" but i want to show only "Label1:Yes" and not the others with "No" value

Comment: Why not just wrap the table row in your if statement that determines if it has a value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not wrap the `tr` in an if statement?  You can reuse the same `$value` variable as you only want to show the value when it is "Yes".

```
<?php
    if ($value == 'Yes')
    {
?>
        <tr>
            <td class='detail_label'><?php echo $label; ?></td>
            <td class='detail_label'><?php echo $value; ?></td>
        </tr>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the code... i changed it to !=='No' as i had also different field types

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 <table>
    <tbody>
<?php 
foreach ($fields as $field) {
   $displayflag=true; //<--here
$type = $field['s_type'];
$label = $field['s_label'];
$value = Attributes::newInstance()->getValue($item_id, $field['pk_id']);
if ($type == 'checkbox') {
    if ($value == 'checked'){ $value = 'Yes'; }
    else{ $value = 'No';$displayflag=false}; //<--here
}
?>
 <?php if($displayflag){?> //<--here

        <tr>
            <td class='detail_label'><?php echo $label; ?></td>
            <td class='detail_label'><?php echo $value; ?></td>
        </tr>
  <?php }?>//<--here
<?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```